# Resize UITableViewCell containing UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uikit

I've got a few cells containing `UICollecionView`. For row height I use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and `Autolayout`. Is it possible to automatically resize the cell to show the whole content of collection view at once without scrolling?

Having e.g. 4 tags in this Cell:

[image: cell]

EDIT: Autoresizing works properly, but the alignment is incorrect. I'm trying to do everything with pure `Autolayout` without subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. The last row is always correct. I do not know why...

[image: col]

Here's my code, unfortunately in Xamarin:

```
void ConfigureCollectionCell(ProfileEditCollectionCell cell, String property, IList list, nint tag)
{
    cell.propertyName = property;
    cell.collectionView.Tag = tag;
    cell.collectionView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
    cell.collectionView.DataSource = this;
    cell.collectionView.RegisterNibForCell(UINib.FromName("ProfileEntityCell", NSBundle.MainBundle), "profileEntityCell");
    (cell.collectionView.CollectionViewLayout as UICollectionViewFlowLayout).EstimatedItemSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(150, 20);
    var collectionHeight = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(cell.collectionView , NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 1,     cell.collectionView.CollectionViewLayout.CollectionViewContentSize.Height);
    cell.collectionView.AddConstraint(collectionHeight);
}

public UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("profileEntityCell", indexPath) as ProfileEntityCell;
    cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    ConfigureCollectionEntity(cell, indexPath, collectionView.Tag); //not important

    collectionView.SetNeedsUpdateConstraints();
    collectionView.UpdateConstraints();

    return cell as UICollectionViewCell;
}
```

Comment: without scrolling what collection view or tableview , you need that you want all collection view cells  in table view cell and you don't want scroll collection view right ?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to expand this table cell to show whole collection view.

Comment: see the answer hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you first need is  take a IBOutlet of collection view height auto layout  and then set collection view height constant  = collection view content size.height  , and stop collection view scrolling will solve your problem

Comment: happy coding @bubupankowski

Comment: this doesn't work in XCODE 8.3.1 , repeating collectionview iboutlet can't be set as this way

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari This is simple autolayout trick . How it can matter with xcode ? . Please describe your problem